# Ionic and FCM: why call getToken every time the app starts?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

All the tutorials tell me to add getToken to my Angular component. But doesn't that imply that I generate a new token every time the app is started by the user? That would mean a lot of unnecessary traffic for storing the new token at the firebase servers. Why don't you get a token **once** when the app is installed on a phone? By the way I have no idea how to execute code only once when the app is installed but wouldn't that be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase docs:

> Because the token could be rotated after initial startup, you are
> strongly recommended to retrieve the latest updated registration
> token.

So, because the token  can vary due to different situations you don't know, official doc recommends to retrieve always the last updated registration token. Getting the token is not a task to perform once after installation but you have to get new one whenever FCM requires.